# Android: enter keyword in Google search box

Tags: java, javascript, android, search

I'm building an Android app where user insert the answer to some question; based on these answers, the app choose a word to be searched on Google and then open a random link on the search results (a similar functionality ad the old Google "I feel lucky".

I know the best way to search something in Google is to query it using the URL www.google.com/search?=myKeyword.

But in this case, i want the user see the app which automatically:

- Open google.com webpage (inside a webview);
- Enter the keyword in the google search box;
- Hit the Search button;
- Show the first page results;
- Open a random result.

I described the context.
Now the question: what is the better way to enter the keyword in the search box and hit the search button in the webview? I know something is possible with Javascript but, as i don't know JS deeply, i would like to explore some alternative, if any.
If JS is the only solution, could you give me some indication about where to start?

Another way to do it is using HTMLUnit but i prefer not to use it.

Comment: Can i know what a negative vote without any consideration means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution.

Here the code, if anyone needs it:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

      //Browser settings
      WebSettings myBrowserSettings = myBrowser.getSettings();

      //Delete previously stored cookies and disable cookies
      CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
      CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
      cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
      cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false);

      //Prevent cache to be used
      myBrowserSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
      myBrowserSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);

      //General settings
      myBrowserSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
      myBrowserSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
      myBrowserSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

      //FIREFOX 
      myBrowserSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0");

      myBrowserSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
      myBrowserSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
      myBrowserSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
      myBrowserSettings.setLightTouchEnabled(false);
      myBrowserSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

      //Open the browser
      myBrowser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);     
      myBrowser.loadUrl(urlToBrowse);
      myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
          public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
          {
              String word = "My Keyword";

              view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('gbqfq').value = '"+word+"';");  
              view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('gbqfba').click();");  
          }
      });
```

This solution completely works on Android 4.0.4 and a Firefox User Agent.

Antway, if another UserAgent is used (like Chrome, IE or Opera), this solution stops after paisting keyword in search box (i don't know why); the .click() JS doesn't work.

**UPDATE:**
I found that i was losing the reference of the "Search" button because i had Javascript enabled;  so, i tried to load the page without Javascript, enabling JS only when the page is loaded; in this way, everything is working perfectly, with any desktop User Agent.